# 'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'encode'

Tags: numpy, compiler-errors, fpdf

I'm running a code, that basically creates a pdf with a table that contains 3 columns and I'm getting: "'numpy.int32' object has no attribute 'encode'".
Probably the problem of the code is relatable with the way that I´m calling the arrary, but I´m not sure and I don´t know other way since I´m a noobie. Anyone can help me here?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from fpdf import FPDF

utotal = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15])

class PDF(FPDF):
            def header(self):
                self.image(r"c:\users\tomas\Documents\ISEP\5º Ano\TESE\PROGRAMA\TED.png", 10, 8, 25)
                self.set_font("helvetica", "B", 20)
                self.cell(0, 10, "Relatório", border = False, ln = 1, align = "C")
                self.ln(20)

pdf = PDF("P","mm","Letter")

pdf.add_page()

pdf.set_auto_page_break(auto = 1, margin = 15)

pdf.set_font("helvetica", size = 12)


TABLE_TITLE = ("", "Deslocamentos nos nós", "")
TABLE_COL_NAMES = ("Nó", "Valor", "Unidade")
TABLE_DATA = (
    ("u1", utotal[0], "m"),
    ("v1", utotal[1], "m"),
    ("o1", utotal[2], "rad"),
    ("u2", utotal[3], "m"),
    ("v2", utotal[4], "m"),
    ("o2", utotal[5], "rad"),
    ("u3", utotal[6], "m"),
    ("v3", utotal[7], "m"),
    ("o3", utotal[8], "rad"),
    ("u4", utotal[9], "m"),
    ("v4", utotal[10], "m"),
    ("o4", utotal[11], "rad"),
    ("u5", utotal[12], "m"),
    ("v5", utotal[13], "m"),
    ("o5", utotal[14], "rad"),
)

pdf.set_font("helvetica", size=12)
line_height = pdf.font_size * 2
col_width = pdf.epw/3  # distribute content evenly

def render_table_title():
    pdf.set_font(style="B")  # enabling bold text
    for col_name in TABLE_TITLE:
        pdf.cell(col_width, line_height, col_name, border=0)
    pdf.ln(line_height)
    pdf.set_font(style="")  # disabling bold text
render_table_title()

def render_table_header():
    pdf.set_font(style="B")  # enabling bold text
    for col_name in TABLE_COL_NAMES:
        pdf.cell(col_width, line_height, col_name, border=1)
    pdf.ln(line_height)
    pdf.set_font(style="")  # disabling bold text

render_table_header()
for _ in range(1):  # repeat data rows
    for row in TABLE_DATA:
        if pdf.will_page_break(line_height):
            render_table_title()
            render_table_header()
        for datum in row:
            pdf.cell(col_width, line_height, datum, border=1)
        pdf.ln(line_height)
```

Comment: Full error statement, please!

Comment: It´s literally the title.

Comment: No traceback or anything tell you (or us) where the problem occurs?  With relatively few `fpdf` watchers, you'll have to provide more information if you want help (from the more abundant `numpy` users).

Comment: If you try to run the code you will see that a message is shown: return txt.encode(self.core_fonts_encoding).decode("latin-1")
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'encode'

Comment: Sorry, was it solved? If yes, do you mind to share the solution please?